# Scrapy crawler crawls but does not scrape

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-crawler, scrapy

Any idea why this isn't working? I'm a complete newby to scrapy, trying to actually extract the data to a csv file but can't do that if it doesnt scrape. I'm thinking the problem could be in the xpath but all the paths under `def parse_mode` are correct. Could there be another reason it isnt scraping?

Terminal output:

```
2017-01-10 10:31:16 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 213 pages (at 23 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import types
import time
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

import requests
import msgpack

from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector, Selector
from resume_data.items import ResumeDataItem, ResultListItem, WorkItem, SchoolItem, ItemList

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag, NavigableString, Comment
from bs4.element import NavigableString

class ResumeIndeedSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "indeed_resume"
allowed_domains = ["indeed.com"]
start_urls = ['http://www.indeed.com/resumes/mechanical-engineer',
              'http://www.indeed.com/resumes/mechanical-engineering',
              'http://www.indeed.com/resumes/piping-engineer',
              'http://www.indeed.com/resumes/design-engineer',
              'http://www.indeed.com/resumes/project-engineer']

#def __init__(self, filename=None):
        #self.unis    =   list()


rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths = ('//a[contains(@class,"app_link")]')), callback = "parse_item", follow = True),)


def parse_item(self, response):
    hxs     =   Selector(response)
    digest  =   hxs.xpath('//ol[@class="resultsList"]')
    records =   ResumeDataItem()

    url_prefix = 'http://www.indeed.com'

    resume_links   =   digest.xpath('//li[@class="sre"]//div[@class="sre-entry"]')
    names   =   digest.xpath('//a[@target="_blank"]/text()').extract()
    links   =   digest.xpath('//a[@target="_blank"]/@href').extract()

    for name, link in zip(names,links):
        if name not in 'Feedback':
            records['name'] =   name
            records['link'] =   url_prefix+link
            yield Request(records['link'], meta={'item': records}, callback= self.parse_node)


def parse_node(self, response):
    hxs     =   Selector(response)
    records =   ResumeDataItem()

#        name    =   hxs.xpath('/text()').extract()
    name        =   hxs.xpath('//h1[@id="resume-contact"]/text()').extract()
    headline    =   hxs.xpath('//h2[@id="headline"]/text()').extract()
#        locale      =   hxs.xpath('//div[@class="addr" and @itemprop="address"]//p//text()').extract()
    rlocale      =   hxs.xpath('//p[@id="headline_location" and @class="locality"]//text()').extract()
    summary     =   hxs.xpath('//p[@id="res_summary" and @class="summary"]/text()').extract()
    skills      =   list()
    skill       =   hxs.xpath('//div[@id="skills-items" and @class="items-container"]//p//text()').extract()
    if len(skill) != 0:
        skills.append(''.join(skill).encode('utf-8'))        
    skill       =   hxs.xpath('//div[@id="additionalinfo-section" and @class="last"]//div[@class="data_display"]//p//text()').extract()
    if len(skill) != 0:
        skills.append(''.join(skill).encode('utf-8'))        

    resume_links    =   list()
    links       =   hxs.xpath('//div[@id="link-items" and @class="items-container"]//p//text()').extract()
    for link in links:
        resume_links.append(''.join(link).encode('utf-8'))

    workHistory =   ItemList()
    experience  =   hxs.xpath('//div[@id="work-experience-items"]/div')
    for elem in experience:
        item = elem.xpath('div')
        for entry in item:
            workEntry   =   WorkItem()

            title       =   entry.xpath('p[@class="work_title title"]//text()').extract()
            workEntry['title']  =   ''.join(title).encode('utf-8')

            company     =   entry.xpath('div[@class="work_company"]/span/text()').extract()
            workEntry['company']=   ''.join(company).encode('utf-8')

            location    =   entry.xpath('div[@class="work_company"]/div[@class="inline-block"]/span/text()').extract()
            workEntry['work_location']  =   ''.join(company).encode('utf-8')

            dates       =   entry.xpath('p[@class="work_dates"]//text()').extract()
            dates_str   =   ''.join(dates).encode('utf-8').split(' to ')
            if len(dates) > 0:
                if dates_str[0]:
                    workEntry['start_date'] =   dates_str[0]
                if dates_str[1]:
                    workEntry['end_date']   =   dates_str[1]
            else:
                workEntry['start_date'] =   'NULL'
                workEntry['end_date']   =   'NULL'


            description =   entry.xpath('p[@class="work_description"]//text()').extract()
            workEntry['description']    =   ''.join(description).encode('utf-8')

            workHistory.container.append(workEntry)

    eduHistory =   ItemList()
    education  =   hxs.xpath('//div[@id="education-items" and @class="items-container"]/div')
    for elem in education:
        item = elem.xpath('div')
        for entry in item:
            eduEntry    =   SchoolItem()

            degree      =   entry.xpath('p[@class="edu_title"]/text()').extract()
            degree      =   ''.join(degree).encode('utf-8')
            eduEntry['degree']  =   degree

            school      =   entry.xpath('div[@class="edu_school"]/span//text()').extract()
            school      =   ''.join(school).encode('utf-8')
            eduEntry['school']  =   school

            locale      =   entry.xpath('span[@itemprop="addressLocality"]/text()').extract()
            locale      =   ''.join(locale).encode('utf-8')
            eduEntry['locale']  =   locale

            grad_date   =   entry.xpath('p[@class="edu_dates"]/text()').extract()
            dates_str   =   ''.join(grad_date).encode('utf-8').split(' to ')
            if len(grad_date) > 0:
                if len(dates_str) == 2:
                    if dates_str[0]:
                        eduEntry['admit_date']  =   dates_str[0]
                    try:
                        if dates_str[1]:
                            eduEntry['grad_date']   =   dates_str[1]
                    except:
                        pass
                elif len(dates_str) == 1:
                    if dates_str[0]:
                        eduEntry['grad_date']  =   dates_str[0]
                        eduEntry['admit_date'] =   'NULL'
            else:
                eduEntry['admit_date']  =   'NULL'
                eduEntry['grad_date']   =   'NULL'

            eduHistory.container.append(eduEntry)

    records['url']      =   response.url
    records['name']     =   ''.join(name).encode('utf-8')
    records['headline'] =   msgpack.packb(''.join(headline).encode('utf-8'))
    records['locale']   =   ''.join(rlocale).encode('utf-8')
    records['summary']  =   msgpack.packb(''.join(summary).encode('utf-8'))
    records['skills']   =   msgpack.packb(skills)
    records['links']    =   resume_links
    #records['experience']   =   msgpack.packb(workHistory, default=workHistory.encode)
    records['experience'] = workHistory
    records['education']    =   msgpack.packb(eduHistory, default=eduHistory.encode)
    #records['experience']   =   workHistory
    #records['education']    =   eduHistory

    return records`
```

Comment: Did you try changing the `return records` to `yield records` like in the `parse_item` function?

Comment: Tips for debugging (in no particular order): 1) add `self.logger.debug("parse_xxx(%r)" %  response)` (replace with callback name) at the beginning of each callback code block to make sure you are entering the correct callback, checking your CrawlSpider rules that way, 2) test your XPath in `scrapy shell` with sample pages; 3) enable HTTP caching (`HTTPCACHE_ENABLED=True`) so that you don't have to download pages all the time while debugging.

Comment: @GHajba No luck. i'm assuming you mean changing the last line to `yield records` and nothing more.